# How to apply data validation for drop down in excel sheet by C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, excel-addins, vba

I am working on Excel plugin and trying to create the dropdowns for a column which can have another column cells data.

For Example:

Column H's name is `Type` and has data like "Animal, Human".
Column I's name is `Animal` and has data like "Dog, Cat, Rat"
Column J's name is `Dog` and has data like "Dog1, Dog2, Dog3"
Column K's name is `Cat` and has data like "Cat1 , Cat2 , Cat3"
Column L's name is `Rat` and has data like "Rat1 , Rat2 , Rat3"

```
1    H        I        J        K        L
2   Type     Name     Dog      Cat      Rat
3   Animal   Dog      Dog1     Cat1     Rat1
4   Human    Cat      Dog2     Cat2     Rat2
5            Rat      Dog3     Cat3     Rat3
```

I linked column A with column H with this formula:

```
firstRow.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
                "=" + activeWorkSheet.Name + "!" + activeWorkSheet.get_Range("Type").AddressLocal);
```

same formula I applied for `B2` with changing the range name.

Now cell `A1` has a dropdown list of "Animal, Human".

cell `B1`'s dropdown list is dependent on cell `A1`.

So if user is selecting `A1` data as "Animal", the dropdown list of `B1` should be according to `A1`'s dropdown data like "Dog, Cat, Rat, Lion"

Again if user is selecting `D1`, It should be according to selected data as `B1`.

In excel I just selected the cells and go to data validation tab, then select type as list and applied formula like:

```
=indirect($A1)
```

And it is working fine for column `B1`.

How can I apply it by C# code.?

Please let me know If any sentence is not clear.

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want to set the dropdown list in B1 when A1 changed and change D1 list when B1 changed?

Comment: yes exactly. @Alex Butenko